# Google Tag Manager Conversion value mismatch

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Google Tag Assistant showing an error:

> "Conversion value mismatch between  and  tag."

Please review below code snippets.

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = <conversion_id>;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "<conversion_label>";
if (813.00) {
    var google_conversion_value = "813.00";
    var google_conversion_currency = "AED";
}
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */

<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src=""//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/<conversion_id>/?value=813.00&amp;currency_code=AED&amp;label=<conversion_label>&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0""/>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Since it is usually pointless to set a noscript tag in a javascript based tag management system I suggest you simply drop the noscript part.

Comment: If 813.00 is `false` the `google_conversion_value` will be a ReferenceError. You must set `var google_conversion_value = 0`; and then update the value if your statement validates as 813.00.